# VBOXGUESTADITIONS causing conflict

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

Before installing Virtual box i installed Vbox guest addition version 2.2 and know i am unable to install Virtual box version 5.1. it gives conflict error massage. i tried to uninstall Vbox guest addition package with

`sudo apt-get remove Vbox guest addition.iso`

but it  can't removed the package from the directory.

I think the solution may be installing lower version or compatible virtual box version with Vbox guest addition or upgrading the Vbox guest addition version. i don't know how to do this please can i have your help.

Comment: If it's an `.iso` file just right click on it and eject...Let me know then we can continue...

Comment: It's always better to remove a package with 'sudo apt-get autoremove --purge package_name*' command, so, any residual problematic package will be removed too. then update, dist-upgrade and install.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii`. Start new comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.